# Flex : addChild and removeChild Vs setting visible and includeInLayout properties to true and false

Tags: apache-flex

this is a very generic question. 
In a heavy mxml in flex I need to add a bit of ui which will be shown n hidden based on users actions.

I want to know purely from performance perspective which is better

using addChild and removeChild

or

setting visible and includeInLayout properties to true and false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding/removing is better from a performance perspective since the LayoutManager doesn´t need to take of the object. Even if you use `includeInLayout`, a reference to the object is still saved.

Comment: hey then why is includeInLayout still there. Is there any other advantage that we get from it?

Comment: Worth noting that `addChild` and `removeChild` are actually very heavy processes to run and it should not be used as an alternative to `visible` in most cases. If you need to turn something on and off at a somewhat frequent rate, you should use `visible` which will not render that object (saving the runtime time) and not add/remove which adds time. The only time you should use removeChild is if you do not want it to return to the screen any time in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that there will be some functions that still deal with your DisplayObject, so the question you'll have to ask yourself is:

Is the amount of time it takes to re-create your DisplayObject greater than the small amount of processing that will happen to one if it were just hidden?  This question is very subjective.  Also take into account how often you'll have to add it back.

Trying both methods and using the profiler will help you determine this.